# how merge two string simultaneously in c#?

Tags: c#

I currently have the following code:

```
a += 123,456,789;
b += 11,22,33;
c= a + b;
```

This results in 123,456,78911,22,33, but I want the result to be 12311,45622,78933. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: If i understand, you want to sort of _fuse_ them together?

Comment: Just use `Split(',')` for your inputs string and then concatenate two `string[]` by index

Answer (score 0):

Note: ckuri's answer is way better.

You need to ask what the algorithm is for what you're trying to achieve.  I'd say you're looking to "Create a new string, then for both args, get the next 3 elements of string A, append, and then get the next 2 elements of string B, append, until you run out of chars in one of the strings.  Then, return the new string."

There's also some commas to take care of too.  Here's an example:

```
 using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thing t = new Thing();
            Console.WriteLine(t.Merge("123,456,789", "11,22,33"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The incredible THING
    /// </summary>
    public class Thing
    {
        //overly fancy consts
        const int A_STRING_CUT_SIZE = 3;
        const int B_STRING_CUT_SIZE = 2;

        /// <summary>
        /// Merges two codes together
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="A">The first code</param>
        /// <param name="B">The second code</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string Merge(string A, string B)
        {
            //strip 'em
            string aCopy = A.Replace(",", "");
            string bCopy = B.Replace(",", "");
            //prep' 'em
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int aIndex = 0;
            int bIndex = 0;
            //loop 'em
            while (aIndex < aCopy.Length / A_STRING_CUT_SIZE && bIndex < bCopy.Length / B_STRING_CUT_SIZE)
            {
                //build 'em
                sb.Append(aCopy.Substring(aIndex * A_STRING_CUT_SIZE, A_STRING_CUT_SIZE));
                sb.Append(bCopy.Substring(bIndex * B_STRING_CUT_SIZE, B_STRING_CUT_SIZE));
                sb.Append(",");
                //increment 'em
                aIndex++;
                bIndex++;
            }
            //clean 'em
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
            //send 'em back
            return sb.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I hope thing a bit clear, my code:                                                                                                       if (attribute == "ID")
 {
   if (reader.Read())
          {
              Code3 += reader.Value; //Code3 = 123,456,789
          }
  }
  if (attribute == "Balance")
  {
   if (reader.Read())
           {
                 Code4 += reader.Value; //Code3 = 11,22,33
           }
   }
                 Code5 = Code3 + Code4;// Code5 = 123,456,78911,22,33
                 But i need like Code5 = 12311,45622,78933

Comment: Apologies for unhelpful initial post, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Updated again to include your comment's info.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to split the strings at your comma separator; second you can then zip both sequences together; and finally rejoin the combined sequence to a string using your separator. The code would go like follows:

```
var string1 = "123,456,789";
var string2 = "11,22,33";
var combinedStr = string.Join(",", string1.Split(',').Zip(string2.Split(','), (a, b) => a + b)); // returns "12311,45622,78933"
```

Addendum:
If you can't use at least .NET 4.0 required for Zip, you could also use:

```
var string1Parts = string1.Split(',');
var string2Parts = string2.Split(',');
var combinedStr = string.Join(",", string1Parts.Select((s, i) => s + string2Parts[i]).ToArray());
```

Comment: I got the following error message, 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Zip' and no extension method 'Zip' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add "using System.Linq;"

Comment: Sorry my mistake the Zip can use .Net 4.0 and above i am using .network 3.5. Any solution?

Comment: Now it shows this error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look up that the Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<T>) overload was also introduced in .NET 4.0. You can add ToArray() after the select to convert the IEnumerable to an array for the old Join(string, string[]) overload.

Comment: Great bro, now i can able to use this code at .net3.5. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to take each source string, split it on the `','` character, then join the common parts, combined with commas, back into a string. Since it's a bit of code, I put it into a method:

```
static string CombineParts(string a, string b, char delimeter)
{
    if (a == null) return b;
    if (b == null) return a;

    var combinedString = string.Empty;
    var partsOfA = a.Split(delimeter);
    var partsOfB = b.Split(delimeter);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Math.Min(partsOfA.Length, partsOfB.Length); i++)
    {
        combinedString += $"{partsOfA[i]}{partsOfB[i]}{delimeter}";
    }

    // In case either string had more parts than the other, add them to the result
    if (i < partsOfA.Length)
    {
        combinedString += string.Join(delimeter.ToString(), partsOfA.Skip(i));
    }
    else if (i < partsOfB.Length)
    {
        combinedString += string.Join(delimeter.ToString(), partsOfB.Skip(i));
    }

    return combinedString.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

This can be called like:

```
string a = "123,456,789";
string b = "11,22,33";
string c = CombineParts(a, b, ',');

Console.WriteLine($"c = \"{c}\"");
```

**Output**

[image]